# ImportError: cannot import name main when running pip --version command in windows7 32 bit

Tags: python, pip, importerror

I've installed the latest python (2.7.9) bundled with pip and setuptools for windows 32-bit. I've tried reinstalling pip but the problem persists.

Here's the error after running `pip --version` in Administrator cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
  "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
 File "D:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code 
  exec code in run_globals
 File "D:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

Comment: It may be related to file permission there was an issue with python 3.4 [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue21030) that was solved, it worth a check.

Comment: I did the workarounds using the icacls command but the error persists.

Comment: "easy_install -U pip" answer provide at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031277/pip-install-error-cannot-import-name-
unpack-url

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Even though the original question seems to be from 2015, this 'bug' seems to affect users installing `pip-10.0.0` as well.

The workaround is not to modify `pip`, however to change the way pip is called. Instead of calling `/usr/bin/pip` call `pip` via Python itself. For example, instead of the below:

```
pip install <package>
```

If from Python version 2 (or default Python binary is called `python`) do :

```
python -m pip install <package>
```

or if from Python version 3:

```
python3 -m pip install <package>
```

Comment: yeah, I don't remember what I did to fix this but I'm keeping this open for others.

Comment: When I utilized the given command, I got a permissions error (that I also got after altering pip according to catalinpopescu's answer). However, to download packages for the user's scope (so that you do not need administration rights) use: python3 -m pip install <package> --user (works for python3, should also work for python2 although not tested)

Comment: Helped me on a Mac.

Comment: Better answer. Modifying the source code is a swamp.

Comment: This is a really good way to go. It also makes it really easy to get assurance you're using the right version: `python2 -m pip install $package`

Answer (score 254):

The bug is found in pip 10.0.0.

In linux you need to modify file: /usr/bin/pip from:

```
from pip import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

to this:

```
from pip import __main__
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(__main__._main())
```

Comment: It seems this is the solution. I tried this and no problem so far.

Comment: I am using pip 10.0.1 and the bug is still there. You solution helped. Thanks! Have you reported this bug and the solution back to the developers?

Comment: Although this solution works, please refrain from modifying `pip` itself. See a cleaner solution below to call `pip` from Python instead.

Comment: Doesn't help on "pip 10.0.1".

`pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /home/x/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

usage:

     `sudo pip install tensorflow`

output:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
         from pip import main
     ImportError: cannot import name main`

Comment: (Using pip 10.0.1) The bug seems to only affect normal users, so the bugfix works but brakes the superuser activities... kind of weird

Comment: @WanBachtiar Any reason to refrain from modifying pip itself?

Comment: @creepy_driver , manually modifying an installed package to suit the environment  is not recommended because next time you update to another version, i.e. 10.0.3 you would likely to encounter the same issue. The workaround of running `pip` via installed Python will point pip to use the suitable environment correctly.

Comment: In my case, `pip3 -V` gives 18.0, while the `python3-pip` debian package version is at `9.0.1-2`. But yes, this was a solution.

Comment: **Do not modify pip if you are using pipenv!!!**. I was using nginx, flask and uwsgi. But somehow, uwsgi failed to identify the correct virtualenv path given to it. Even though the  absolute path given was correct. I restored pip to it's original state and all was fine thereafter. The problem was on **Ubuntu 16.04** though.

Comment: This bug seems to persist even in pip 18.1 (tested: python 2.7).
I just had to apply this patch on pip on fresh installed Debian Jessie 9.6.

Comment: it resolved my problem with pip 18.1, Python 3.6.7, Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: This bug still exists in pip 18, I wonder why no one hasn't fixed this problem

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

Comment: I do really agree with Wan Bachtiar

Answer (score 58):

On Ubuntu Server 16, I have the same problem with python27. Try this:

Change

```
from pip import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

To

```
from pip._internal import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Worked on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is not a good idea. As mentioned in another answer by @RichardElkins: "Folks should not waste their time editing installed files not intended to be modified after installation"

Answer (score 22):

On Windows 10, I used the following commands to downgrade pip:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
python -m pip install pip==9.0.3
```

This should also work on Linux and Mac too.

Comment: It should be python -m pip install pip==9.0.3

Comment: @elelias Oh, I didn't realize that. thanks for telling me!

Comment: I had to `python easy_install.py pip==9.0.3` because after the first line, pip wasn't found.

Comment: Works on Linux and Mac too.  It's a work-around until pip/pip3 10 is fixed.  Folks should not waste their time editing installed files not intended to be modified after installation..

Comment: I had path issues after the upgrade, i did the following to make it work. sudo python -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python-pip --reinstall

Comment: this worked. I had to add --user in the end due to permission issue.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, but uninstall and reinstall with apt and pip didn't work for me.

I saw another solution that presents a easy way to recover pip3 path:

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall
```

Comment: I had python 2.7, so i had to alter the command to match python 2.7 sudo python -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python-pip --reinstall

Comment: works perfectly on ubuntu but I think it won't work on windows

Answer (score 8):

i fixed the problem by reinstalling pip using `get-pip.py`.

1. Download get-pip from official link: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
2. run it using commande: `python get-pip.py`.

And pip is fixed and work perfectly.

Comment: Change python `get-pip-py` to python `get-pip.py`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS if you've installed python via Homebrew, change the line in `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip`

from

```
from pip.internal import main
```

to

```
from pip._internal import main
```

Or use this one liner: `sed -i '' "s/from pip import main/from pip._internal import main/" /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip`

### Explanation:

The issue is caused by the changes in pip version 10 moving internal namespace under `main._internal` and the bin script put in place by homebrew still looking it from the old place (where it used to be in version 9). Issue and some discussion https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240

Answer (score 1):

If you have a hardlink to pip in your `PATH` (i.e. if you have multiple python versions installed) and then you upgrade pip, you may also encounter this error.

The solution consists in creating the hardlink again. Or even better, stop using hardlinks and use softlinks.

Comment: how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, I had the same problem. `PIP 19` was already installed in my system but wasn't showing up. The error was `No Module Found`.

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
python -m pip install pip==9.0.3
```

Downgrading `pip` to 9.0.3 worked fine for me.

Comment: How are you uninstalling pip, then using it to reinstall itself?

Answer (score 0):

For those having similar trouble using pip 10 with PyCharm, download the [latest version](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) here

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# GENERATED BY DEBIAN

import sys

# Run the main entry point, similarly to how setuptools does it, but because
# we didn't install the actual entry point from setup.py, don't use the
# pkg_resources API.i
try:
    from pip import main
except ImportError:
    from pip._internal import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that works with Ubuntu, but may fix the problem on windows too:

Just call

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem in ubuntu 18.04 when trying to use python3.6:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/lib/python3.6
```

You can move the folder to another place using mv instead of deleting it too, for testing:

```
mv ~/.local/lib/python3.6 ./python3.6_old
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal linux.

```
hash -d pip
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, welcome to Stack Overflow. To aid other users facing this problem, please could you add to you answer to clarify what this command does and how it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, in 2020 using Python3, the solution to this problem was to move the Python installation to the `cloud-init` startup script which instantiated the VM.

We had been encountering this same error when we had been trying to install Python using scripts that were called by users later in the VM's life cycle, but moving the same Python installation code to the `cloud-init` script eliminated this problem.

Answer (score -1):

It works on ubuntu 16.04. 
Step 1:

```
 sudo gedit /home/user_name/.local/bin/pip
```

a file opens with the content:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Change the `main` to `__main__` as it appears below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import __main__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(__main__._main())
```

Save the file and close it. And you are done!