# can`t upgrade pip to the newest version 9.0.1 (OS:ubuntu 16.04LTS)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

**OS:** `ubuntu 16.04LTS`

**Python:** `2.7.12 + Anaconda2-4.2.0 (64 bit)`

I typed `pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL` to install tensorflow but terminal showed that my pip verson was `8.1.1`, however version `9.0.1` is available.

Then I typed `pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade but it showed 
`Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages`,

I still can't use pip version 9.0.1 to install tensorflow. Does anyone know what's going on ??

Answer (score 44):

`sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip`

sudo is "super user do". This will allow you to execute commands as a super user. The H flag tells sudo to keep the home directory of the current user. This way when pip installs things, like pip itself, it uses the appropriate directory.

Comment: It is absolutely an answer to the question. If you run the command, it will install pip properly, even if pip thinks it has the most recent version. This is because it could be caused by a permissions issue, though generally one should not have to pip using sudo, sometimes it happens.

Comment: I thought it wasn't a good idea to use sudo with python. Is it okay with pip ?

Comment: Usually a bad idea to use sudo with pip because of permissions,  home directory, and linked binaries issues. However, in the event that your pip upgrade is not working, and it's caused by permissions issues (which can be difficult to diagnose, I've found, but open to suggestion) then this will _usually_ fix your pip installation. **It's important to keep the home directory of your current user**, however.

Comment: discovered that as of Ubuntu 16.04 pip is aliased to pip3 so that is why both sudo and pip3 commands are working for some people. Perhaps, depending on the root cause of the issue in your case pip3 is the better command. YMMV. try `ls \`which pip\` && ls \`which pip2\` && ls \`which pip3\` ` first

Comment: Thank you very much, what should I do if mine is : `/home/mike/.local/bin/pip
/home/mike/.local/bin/pip2
/home/mike/.local/bin/pip3` ?

Comment: If they're all in your local, assuming you are `mike` on this system, you shouldn't need to use `sudo` as you should have ownership of that directory. Check your permissions with `ls -halp /home/mike/.local/bin/` to see if you are owner. If you are then there's some other issue. Try using the pip(s) directly like `$> python -m ./home/mike/.local/bin/pip3 --upgrade pip` or perhaps `$> pip2 --upgrade pip`. You may even try using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-pip`, though that may install yet another `pip` and re-link `$> pip` to still a different `pip`...welcome to pip hell

Comment: `pip --version --verbose` is also your friend and may lend some insight into your specific problem.  Of course, you can also do this with your individual `pip`s as in the same format as above

Comment: Also be weary that if you are in a virtualenv you can install even yet another version of pip.
On my own system just now, in order to try to answer you again, I wound up going through all these steps and still needing the original `sudo -H ...` solution in order to update to 10. I had a system pip and thusly it was owned by wheel.

Comment: This is a great solution. Also big props on adding the -H flag, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: solution without using sudo?

Comment: @CharlieParker I'm not aware of one. It's, sadly, kind of the point of this answer. Hopefully you have admin rights on your dev machine. I go into much detail above about why it's necessary in this specific case. Best of luck, this one can be a beast.

Comment: @CharlieParker I see that you are on a linux HPC cluster. There is a way to get sudo to work in that instance, though it seems that you are having some other permissions issue. Perhaps check the group permissions on `which pip` ?  I also go into more detail on finding permissions issues above ;) It sounds like it will be a `chown` thing, hopefully, but I don't have enough info to answer better than this.

Answer (score 21):

I had this same problem.  Not sure what is going on.  I use both python and python3 and have both a pip and a pip3.  By chance I did the following and it seems to have fixed the problem.

> pip3 install -U pip

resulting in

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 8.1.2
Uninstalling pip-8.1.2:
  Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.2
Successfully installed pip-9.0.1
```

Comment: That only upgrades pip for python3 and does not answer the original question at all.

Comment: since this answer has more votes than the correct answer, and because this answer is irrelevant to the asked question, I am downvoting. Sorry, thought you should know why though.

Comment: Thats fine.  However I tried the "correct" answer and it failed to help me.  This "incorrect" answer fixed my problem.

Comment: It's not an issue of correct versus incorrect. It's an issue of actually adressing the OPs issue or not, which you did not, though it seems to the untrained eye that you did. Basically, you used python3 to install python2's package manager, which is super wacky btw. I would be surprised to learn that this doesn't complicate the issue for others.  Glad it worked for you though.

Comment: @Metagrapher - As is often the case, differing causes may result in similar problem symptoms.  It seems it could be so in this case.  Debugging is enhanced by keeping an open mind and examining all possibilities.

Comment: Did that work for you anyway? I needed `sudo -H ...` as the other suggested. Without, I got a PermissionError. Did you happen to change `sudoers`?

Comment: I got the following: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 570, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-

Answer (score 21):

I have the same problem. But my `python` is under `/usr/bin`. I tried `sudo -H pip install -U pip`, which didn't work. However, when I removed the `pip` installed by system package manager with

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip python3-pip
```

, the problem was solved. It seems that `pip` installed with system package manager is not consistent with `pip` wrapped up with `python`.

Comment: Same problem for me. There seems to be a conflict between 2 pip installs ... Removing python-pip from apt, and running "pip install --upgrade pip" solvde the problem

Comment: Good catch! I had a feeling - my pip3 finally let me upgrade pip to 9.0.1, which is only half of what I needed, but the very next command I issued complained about 8.1.2. As it turns out, they were *both* 8.1.2 still. AFAIK that means I had four Pips to go with my two Pythons, and as far as my system is concerned, they're all the real Slim Shady. Meanwhile, between the average time between updates from 2.6-3.6 and the fact that they jumped from 2.7-3.0, we could have Python 4.0 in mid-April.

Comment: on a fresh install of Ubuntu16.04 LTS  all this answer did was remove pip completely - so did not address the posted problem at all

Comment: try `ls \`which pip\` && ls \`which pip2\` && ls \`which pip3\`` first. Also be careful that pip in a venv can be a different pip than outside of one...because you can have entire installs of python in venvs...which you should be compartmentalizing your dependencies.

Comment: solution without using sudo?

Comment: @CharlieParker, I could not think of a way to remove system packages without sudo. But  this problem doesn't occur when I use latest anaconda with python3.

Answer (score 17):

For me none of the above solutions worked, except
`easy_install -U pip`

UPDATE:
`easy_install` was part of `python-setuptools` but from version `39.0.1-2`, it is no longer part of it. See [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-setuptools/39.0.1-2).

Comment: followed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/49900741/4361073 (to solve the main import error - seemingly caused by the update request).

Comment: @parasrish both problems are common but, independent of each other.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: this seemed to download things but then pip didn't work anyway:
```
(automl-meta-learning) [miranda9@golubh1 automl-proj]$ pip install -e .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miranda9/.local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

Comment: `(automl-meta-learning) [miranda9@golubh1 automl-proj]$ easy_install -U pip
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/28/91f26bd088ce8e22169032100d4260614fc3da435025ff389ef1d396a433/pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=51f1c7514530bd5c145d8f13ed936ad6b8bfcb8cf74e10403d0890bc986f0033
`

Comment: `Best match: pip 20.2.4
Processing pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl to /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Adding pip 20.2.4 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning/bin
Installing pip3 script to /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning/bin
Installing pip3.8 script to /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning/bin
`

Comment: `Installed /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-20.2.4-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip`

Answer (score 9):

Try updating pip using conda as follows:

`conda update pip`

Thereafter try installing tensorflow. [See this](https://anaconda.org/jjhelmus/tensorflow)

Comment: @ZongHan-Li Please select my answer as best then.

Comment: @ZongHan-Li Please select this answer as correct so that it will float above the other incorrect answers.

Comment: I think this should not be the accepted answer as in my case I wasn't using `conda` at all. Hence not a very generalized solution.

Comment: This seems like a fantastic idea but it didn't work for me... :(

Comment: @CharlieParker conda obviates pip and provides virtual environments, so if conda works for you, then you shouldn't need to mess with pip. In fact, if you can avoid using pip for packages, do that. Often on OSX, because it ships with an OS version of python 2.7, this can be a major headache. Conda should not install pip, however. this just gives you a second install of pip. Pyenv seems to be The Way these days. https://towardsdatascience.com/which-python-package-manager-should-you-use-d0fd0789a250?gi=35c7f6d4362b

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem BUT because of **permission**. So simple solution for me:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I can't use sudo in a HPC :(

Answer (score 3):

First, a discussion of the relationship between python and pip.  Then how to apply that to your Anaconda - tensorflow problem.

---

"Pip" is a python package, meaning it must be run by a python interpreter.  The file(s) you see when calling `which pip` (`which pip3`) are actually python scripts, and they are effectively aliasing as follows:

- `pip ...` results in calling `python2.7 -m pip ...`
- `pip3 ...` results in calling `python3.5 -m pip ...`

Furthermore, in your environment `pip` is the alias target of `pip2`,

Each version of python has it's own search path, so each version finds a different version of the pip package.  Moreover,

when the `python2.7/sitepackages/pip` is called by `python2.7`, it will install in 
`/home/<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`  (or the window equivalent)

and when the `python3.5/site-packages/pip` is called by `python3.5`, it will install in 
`/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`  (or the window equivalent)

It is impossible for `python2.7` to call `python3.5/.../pip`, and impossible for `python3.5` to call `python2.7/.../pip` - so fortunately we don't even have to consider those combinations, whew!

Why did your system not want to upgrade the `pip` in `python2.7/.../site-packages`? My guess is that was by design.  By the way, are you sure `tensorflow` is written in `python2.7` and not `python3.5`?

---

To get back to your question:  I found this link which may be of interest to you:

[Installing Tensorflow on windows Anaconda2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384000/installing-tensorflow-on-windows-anaconda2)

It appears that the OP was trying to use tensorflow which required python3.5, into Anaconda2 which uses python2.7.

Perhaps you could upgrade to Anaconda3 which uses python3.5?  (There might be other ways, but upgrading Anaconda seems klike the one with the least liklihood of cross version problems).

Then you install your tensorflow module with

`python3 -m pip install tensorflow`

Comment: OP was on Ubuntu 16.04LTS, using, presumably the latest tensorflow at the time, which was 0.11.0, which ran on py2.7 on linux, as available on Anaconda Cloud https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow/files?version=0.11.0 Just FYI, since the particular error the OP was experiencing was a Linux permissions issue. But hopefully this explanation helps ppl understand how pip works a little better

Answer (score 3):

If you're only installing things to one user account it is also possible to use `pip install --user --upgrade pip` avoiding the question of to `sudo` or not to `sudo`... just be careful not to use that account with system wide installation of `pip` goodies.

Answer (score 1):

**cannot install pip 9 for python3 on ubuntu16 with pip or pip3**

*solve by:*  `sudo apt-get upgrade python3-pip`  (here may be run the `apt update` first.)

`pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /home/roofe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)`

---

`roofe@utnubu:~$ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 14kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-9.0.1`

*note: the upper command only successly installed for python2.*

`roofe@utnubu:~$ pip3 install --upgrade pip3
Collecting pip3
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip3
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
roofe@utnubu:~$  pip install --upgrade pip3
Collecting pip3
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip3
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

Answer (score 1):

Unsurprisingly none of the answers here worked for me either. What did work was to go to https://pypi.org/project/pip/9.0.3/#files and download the wheel file. Then I ran `pip install --user pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl`. That successfully got me to `9.0.3`.

After that I did `pip install --user --upgrade` and it successfully upgraded me to `10.0.0`. I suppose I could have directly installed `10.0.0` but I also wanted to double check that there wasn't anything else wrong in the chain.

Anyway, here is where you can download the latest pip: https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an actual solution, but the output of the commands above, and who knows, maybe useful for some*

To sum up what's going on here. 
The system is a Raspbian 8 Jessie LITE running on a Raspberry Pi 3 meta B, so in short, it's a Debian based Linux OS just like Ubuntu.

On this system the command `pip install --upgrade pip` doesn't do the job. My thinking is it just simply can't do it because of the required Debian packages which are installed with the `sudo apt-get upgrade python-pip` command (about 27MB). Pip just simply not allowed to upgrade Debian packages.

I think the source of difference in results for the self-updating command is a minor version difference which doesn't need system level upgrade can be done like that but every other case will require an actual software upgrade, but I may be wrong. 
Based on my little investigation the correct solution for Debian Linux is:
**`sudo apt-get upgrade python-pip`**
or
**`sudo apt-get upgrade python3-pip`**
as others stated before.

```
    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip show pip
    ---
    Name: pip
    Version: 1.5.6
    Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    Requires: 

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip3 show pip
    ---
    Name: pip
    Version: 1.5.6
    Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
    Requires: 

    pi@lalaland:~ $ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
    Downloading/unpacking pip from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=717cdffb2833be8409433a93746744b59505f42146e8d37de6c62b430e25d6d7
      Downloading pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB): 1.3MB downloaded
    Installing collected packages: pip
      Found existing installation: pip 1.5.6
        Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
    Successfully installed pip
    Cleaning up...

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip show pip
    ---
    Name: pip
    Version: 1.5.6
    Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    Requires: 

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip3 show pip
    ---
    Name: pip
    Version: 1.5.6
    Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
    Requires: 

    pi@lalaland:~ $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
    Downloading/unpacking pip from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=717cdffb2833be8409433a93746744b59505f42146e8d37de6c62b430e25d6d7
      Downloading pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB): 1.3MB downloaded
    Installing collected packages: pip
      Found existing installation: pip 1.5.6
        Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS
    Successfully installed pip
    Cleaning up...

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip show pip
    ---
    Name: pip
    Version: 1.5.6
    Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    Requires: 

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip3 show pip
    ---
    Name: pip
    Version: 1.5.6
    Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
    Requires: 

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip -version

    Usage:   
      pip <command> [options]

    no such option: -e

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip --version
    pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip3 --version
    pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

The commands seem to have no effect what so ever.
So time to try to upgrade `pip` with `apt-get`.

```
    pi@lalaland:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade python-pip
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... python-pip is already the newest version.
    Done
    The following packages have been kept back:
      python-openssl python3-openssl
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      curl git git-core git-man gnupg gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgv libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libicu52 libmad0 libperl5.20 libpoppler46
      libprocps3 libsdl-image1.2 libsnmp-base libsnmp30 libssl1.0.0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 openssl perl perl-base
      perl-modules poppler-utils procps wget xdg-utils
    30 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
    Need to get 27.2 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 731 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libperl5.20 armhf 5.20.2-3+deb8u11 [1,348 B]
    :
    Get:30 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main xdg-utils all 1.1.0~rc1+git20111210-7.4+deb8u1 [65.1 kB]             
    Fetched 27.2 MB in 15s (1,767 kB/s)                                                                                                  
    Reading changelogs... Done
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    :
    Setting up xdg-utils (1.1.0~rc1+git20111210-7.4+deb8u1) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip show pip
    ---
    Name: pip
    Version: 1.5.6
    Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    Requires: 

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip3 show pip
    ---
    Name: pip
    Version: 1.5.6
    Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
    Requires: 

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip --version
    pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip3 --version
    pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)

    pi@lalaland:~ $ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
    Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (10.0.1)

    pi@lalaland:~ $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
    Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
    Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (10.0.1)
```

at this point `pip --version` and `pip3 --version` still returns wrong version numbers.
Although after a soft-reboot (`sudo init 6`):

```
    pi@lalaland:~ $ sudo init 6

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip show pip
    Name: pip
    Version: 10.0.1
    Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
    Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
    Author: The pip developers
    Author-email: python-virtualenv@groups.google.com
    License: MIT
    Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    Requires: 
    Required-by: 

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip3 show pip
    Name: pip
    Version: 10.0.1
    Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
    Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
    Author: The pip developers
    Author-email: python-virtualenv@groups.google.com
    License: MIT
    Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
    Requires: 
    Required-by: 

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip --version
    pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

    pi@lalaland:~ $ pip3 --version
    pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip (python 3.4)
```

All version numbers are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the pip installed by system package manager

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
```

than I needed to dwonload it from the dist page

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

that solved the problem