# Installing Tensorflow on windows Anaconda2

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to install tensorflow on Ananconda2 in windows 64 bit. I've tried the following steps:

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5 

activate tensorflow 

conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Tensorflow got installed successfully and i could check that in Anaconda prompt. 
However, when I open my python2 Jupyter notebook and try with the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get an error says "module tensorflow is not found". Could you please help!

Comment: You mention python3 while installing tensorflow, and open a python2 jupyter notebook. I think this is the problem

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of this. I was not able to install tensorflow on Python 2.7 and the academic project which i've to work should be on python2 notebook but on python3.

Comment: Try changing your kernel from pyhton 2 to python 3 or to your tensorflow env. If you strictly want to use python 2, I'm afraid you will have to install tensorflow for python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:- (Note:- This will surely work for all!!)

Step 1:- conda search python

Step 2:- conda install python=3.5.2

Step 3:- pip install tensorflow

Step 4:- import tensorflow as tf

Done!!