# File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module> from pip import main ImportError: cannot import name main

Tags: python, flask, pip

I am trying to run a webpage using python flask and connecting it with the database of MySQL and while installing MySQL packages I'm receiving this error.

[image]

I'm doing this on ec2 Linux AWS.

Comment: What's the output of `pip --version`? Might be related to: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240

Comment: pip 10.0.1 from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip3 - cannot import name 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/python-pip3-cannot-import-name-main)

Comment: it didn't helped me

Comment: Did you try `python3 -m pip install mysql`?

Comment: Please replace your screenshot with actual copy-pasted text.

Answer (score 81):

## TL;DR

1. The 'ideal' solution (Ubuntu/Debian way):
   `$ python -m pip uninstall pip`  to uninstall the new pip 10 and retain your Ubuntu/Debian-provided patched pip 8. For a *system-wide* installation of modules use `apt` wherever possible (unless you are in a virtualenv), more on it below. In older Ubuntu/Debian versions, always add `--user` flag when using pip outside of virtualenvs (installs into `~/.local/`, default in python-pip and python3-pip since 2016).
2. If you *still* want to use the new pip 10 exclusively, there are 3 quick workarounds:

   - simply re-open a new bash session (a new terminal tab, or type `bash`) - and pip 10 becomes available (see `pip -V`). debian's pip 8 remains installed but is broken; or
   - `$ hash -d pip && pip -V`  to refresh pip pathname in the $PATH. debian's pip 8 remains installed but is broken; or
   - `$ sudo apt remove python-pip && hash -d pip` (for Python 3 it's python3-pip) -- to uninstall debian's pip 8 completely, in favor of your new pip 10.

**Note:** You will always need to add `--user` flag to non-debian-provided pip 10, unless you are in a virtualenv! Your use of pip 10 system-wide, outside of virtualenv, is not really supported by Ubuntu/Debian. Never `sudo pip`!

Details:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221#issuecomment-382069604
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240#issuecomment-381673100

---

So, here we have **Python 2.7.12** in **Ubuntu 16.04** ec2 machine, and get **ImportError: cannot import name main** when trying to use pip. It's caused by the `pip install --upgrade pip` command: that installs the latest pip version 10 alongside Ubuntu's default pip version from python-pip debian package from OS distribution (the system Python installation), completely bypassing Ubuntu `apt` subsystem. It breaks the Ubuntu's default pip: the debian-patched launcher script from python-pip (system-installed to /usr/bin/pip*) tries to do import main() from your newly installed pip 10 library, but with a different import path, so it fails.

This error is discussed in more detail in a [developer thread](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221) of the pip issue tracker, including a few proposed **solutions**, such as:

- The `$ hash -d pip` command: when `hash` is invoked, the full pathname of pip is determined by searching the directories in $PATH and remembered. Any previously-remembered pathname is discarded. The `-d` option causes the shell to "forget" the remembered location of the given package name; or
- Similarly, you can simply re-open a new bash session (a new terminal tab) to refresh pip pathname in $PATH; or
- You could just use a versioned `pip2` command (or `pip3` for Python 3) instead of `pip` to invoke the older system-installed launcher `/usr/bin/pip2` , whereas any pip script located in `$HOME/.local/bin` dir (pip, pip2, pip2.7) will invoke your new user-installed pip 10 version;
- You can also use the versioned Python commands in combination with the `-m` switch to run the appropriate copy of pip, for example:
  `$ python2 -m pip install --user SomePackage` # default Python 2
  `$ python2.7 -m pip install --user SomePackage` # specifically Python 2.7
  That is handy if you have several versions of Python and need an extension from PyPI, such as your MySQL-python module (MySQLdb) or a Flask-MySQL, for a specific Python version. The `--user` switch is only required outside of virtualenv.
- Or, uninstall **one** of the two pips – [either user-installed or system-installed](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221#issuecomment-384711337) – to resolve the conflict:
  `$ python -m pip uninstall pip` – to remove your manually-installed pip in favour of the previously installed Ubuntu-shipped version from python-pip debian package (python3-pip for Python 3); it is slightly older, but it finds and installs latest modules from PyPI just fine, and has a working pip command in the $PATH by default; or
  `$ sudo apt-get remove python-pip` – to uninstall Ubuntu-provided pip in favour of your latest pip 10; if it is not accessible via the short `pip` command, just add your `$HOME/.local/bin` directory to your $PATH environment variable to use `pip` command (see above).
  **Note:** Ubuntu 16.04 pip v8.1.1 and the latest pip v10.0.1 produce exactly the same PyPI index search results and can pull the same module versions;
- Finally, you could ignore both pips altogether in favor of APT, and install Python packages system-wide from Ubuntu repo with:
  `$ apt search <python-package>`  # or `apt-cache search` in older Ubuntu
  `$ apt show <python-package>`    # e.g. python-flask
  `$ sudo apt install <python-package>`  # or `sudo apt-get install`
  Packages prefixed with `python-` are for Python 2; with `python3-` are for Python 3.
  Standard apt-get installation method may be what you need. For example, in your case:
  `python-mysqldb` - Python interface to MySQL <- a fork of MySQLdb == **MySQL-python**
  `python-flask-sqlalchemy` - SQL Alchemy support
  `python-pymysql` - pure Python MySQL driver
  In fact, python-packages from Ubuntu repository are [preferred](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/#debian-ubuntu) whenever possible, particularly in case of heavy system dependencies or when used [system-wide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95037/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-python-packages/116645#116645). 
  Of course, the amount of Python packages in Ubuntu repository (few thousand!) is relatively smaller compared to PyPI (and have only one version of them), because any OS repository is lagging slightly behind PyPI versions. But the upside of APT is that all the Ubuntu-provided packages underwent integration testing within Ubuntu, plus apt-get quickly resolves heavy dependencies like C extensions automatically. You will always get the system libraries you need as part of the apt install, but with pip you have [no such guarantees](http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/installing_on_debian.html).
  APT may not be an option, however, if you really need only the latest (or certain older) package version, or when it can only be found at PyPI, or when modules need to be isolated; then pip is indeed more appropriate tool. If you have to use `pip install` command on Ubuntu instead of `apt-get install`, please ensure it runs in an isolated virtual development environment, such as with [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv) (`sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`), or using a built-in `venv` module (available in python3 only), or at a per-user level (`pip install --user` command option), but *not* system-wide (never `sudo pip`!).

**Note:** Using `sudo pip` command (with root access) on Ubuntu/Debian should be avoided, because it [interferes](https://askubuntu.com/a/116645) with the operation of the system package manager (apt) and may affect Ubuntu OS [components](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2379169&p=13719476#post13719476) when a system-used python module is unexpectedly upgraded, particularly by dependencies on another pip package. It is advised to never use Pip to change system-wide Python packages, as these are managed by apt-get on Ubuntu.

Comment: This is the correct answer, not only explaining the root cause but also providing all the available options (mainly: reverting back to old pip 8 provided by Debian/Ubuntu, or keep using pip 10 but with --user switch everytime). Great answer!

Comment: Up-voted for the completeness and the warning about `sudo pip`. Excellent answer :)

Answer (score 36):

These steps worked for me.

**1-** Uninstall the pip update from python.
**2-** Uninstall pip package from your Ubuntu.
**3-** Check that pip binary is not longer in your system.

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
apt remove python-pip
whereis pip
```

**4-** Download and install pip. ([credits for VanDragt.com](https://vandragt.com/blog/2017/10/how-to-install-pip-and-pipenv-properly-on-ubuntu-17-10/))

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O /tmp/get-pip.py
sudo python3 /tmp/get-pip.py
pip install --user pipenv
pip3 install --user pipenv
echo "PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
whereis pip
```

Now you should be able to install any pip package you want.

Answer (score 10):

My cent, I had the same `ImportError: cannot import name main`.

My system is a *Linux Ubuntu* distro, I have executed this command:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
```

This has removed one local (for the user) `pip` version.

I had already an older `pip`/`pip2` system executable (`apt-get` installed in ancient times) that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

[As suggested in pip's github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240#issue-314425497)

The temporary fix is -

Edit your `/usr/bin/pip` file and comment the line importing main and edit it

```
#from pip import main
from pip._internal import main as main
```

Worked perfectly for me.
Note - **this is a temporary fix**. Wait for team pip to fix this.

OR

```
from pip import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

to this:

```
from pip import __main__
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(__main__._main())
```

As suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210269/importerror-cannot-import-name-main-when-running-pip-version-command-in-windo).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Check the **python version** you use

```
# Python --version
```

and try installing **for eg if your version is 2.7**

```
#python2.7 <package name>
```

Will work fine......

Comment: Have you ever used pip at all? `python2.7 <package name> ` in which world this works?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue after pip 19 upgrade. So I did the following to fix the problem.

**pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3**

instead of

pip install -U pip