# ImportError: cannot import name main in virtual environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, importerror, python-2.6

I have python3.6.5 and pip 19.0.2 on my ubuntu.
I need to install a package which works in python2.6. I created a virtual environment using

conda create -n myenv python=2.6

I activated the virtual environment and installed pip using

sudo apt install python-pip.

It gave no errors and installed pip. However, when I try to use pip it gives the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leila/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/pip", line 4, in 
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main

Thanks,
Leila

Comment: As conda provides own pip in myenv, installing another system-wide instance of pip with the sudo command was excessive. Mixing both pips causes problems. If you use conda, try to rollback by `sudo apt remove python-pip`, then just close/open the terminal. Please check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49988228/9575715) for more.