# Python: pip installer reinstall

Tags: python, pip

I just updated by pip installer to 10.0.1 and now I am getting the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

when I try to `pip install <module>`

Is there a was to go back to pip 9.x.x?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python troubleshooting: ImportError: cannot import name 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969308/python-troubleshooting-importerror-cannot-import-name-main)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can downgrade to the latest 9.x version (9.0.3 at the time of writing) using

```
python -m pip install -U "pip<10"
```

Comment: Is there a command like this for windows? I assume that is for Linux(?)

Comment: I get 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Comment: Try double quotes

Comment: I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'main'` again. I'll try downloading it

Comment: Try using `python -m pip` as per [this comment](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240#issuecomment-383115342)