# Unable to install pip and packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm using python 3.6. Pip is installed along with python. Seems like pip isn't showing up. Tried various solutions available here nothing worked. Please help me solve this.

**Verifications done:**
Path is set as `C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts`
Added host entries for all 3

**PIP error:**

```
C:\Users\>pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

**Tried solutions:**

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org {package name}

C:\Users\>pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'

C:\Users>python3 -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python3 -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python3 -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org {package name}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org {package name}
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

**Using below version**

```
C:\Users\>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
pip2
```

For python 2. And

```
pip3
```

For python 3

And do it from an admin cmd line.

Comment: C:\Users\>pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org {package name}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'

Answer (score 0):

Check you have added paths to the these directories (if you are using python3.x versions) - 
C:\Users\tojose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3.x and for pip 
C:\Users\tojose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3.x\Scripts as pip*.exe's are 
stored here.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\NSSAppLogs\FW-JetBrains-PyCharm Community Edition-2017.3-3264-171.4694.38;C:\Program Files\Python36;C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts;

Comment: This is the path added in env var

Comment: Python by default get s installed in local user folder not under program files. Change your path like this - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36 and %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the full path for both `pip` and the package you want to install.

Example (for Python 3.6):

*C:\Python36\Scripts\pip install C:\Python36\requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl*

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, I had the same problem. `PIP 19` was already installed in my system but wasn't showing up. The error was `No Module Found`.

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
python -m pip install pip==9.0.3
```

Downgrading `pip` to 9.0.3 worked fine for me.

I already answered it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59618506/5375291)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and have tried several commands without a result. I just simply upgraded my pip version from 19.10 to version 20.3.3 and now it's working fine.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

(for windows)

[image]

Note: you are applying the pip command inside the Python REPL, which is wrong.
By using `exit()` function come out from Python and write like this.

[image]

In my case I have already installed a new version.