# ImportError: cannot import name main when running pip with pip version 18.0, ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I got error `cannot import name main` when i tried to running pip. I had tried modify file **/usr/bin/pip** to

```
from pip import __main__
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(__main__._main())
```

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210269/importerror-cannot-import-name-main-when-running-pip-version-command-in-windo) and i got another error `module object has no attribute _main`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about trying the following on python interpreter?  `from pip import __main__; print(dir(__main__))`?

Comment: @KotaMori Thx.. After restart my computer, the changes have taken effect. I checked it again, and the previous changes were still there, so weird. Seems restart's always right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the third answer on that page? The import line which worked for me was:

```
from pip._internal import main
```

I left the other lines alone.

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work before restart my computer. It's bloody weird. Thx anyway.