# How to fix pip : cannot import name main? (pip is installed and pip3 works fine)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

The problem is when I run `pip3 --version` it works fine and produce

> pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

So I decided to install pip using `sudo apt install python-pip` and works fine producing

> python-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1).

But when I try to run `pip --version` the following error shows up

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in 
>           from pip import main
>       ImportError: cannot import name main

I already check this post [Error after upgrading pip: cannot import name 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main) , but my problem only occurs when I'm using pip (python 2.7). Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turns out to be the same as bug in pip 10.0 although I'm using pip 18.0, the bug is still there.

The solution is by modifying file: /usr/bin/pip `sudo vim /usr/bin/pip` 

from:

```
from pip import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
sys.exit(main())
```

to

```
from pip import __main__
if __name__ == '__main__':
sys.exit(__main__._main())
```

credits : [ImportError: cannot import name main when running pip --version command in windows7 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210269/importerror-cannot-import-name-main-when-running-pip-version-command-in-windo)