# Error while installing ggplot in python

Tags: python, python-ggplot

I am getting this error when trying to install `ggplot` in Python:

> ImportError: cannot import name unpack_url

I am using the following command:

```
sudo pip install ggplot
```

This error is in a linux environment, running fedora 21.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pip install error: cannot import name 'unpack\_url'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031277/pip-install-error-cannot-import-name-unpack-url)

Comment: The error is same but this is happening in a linux environment. The other post is in windows.

Comment: The fix mentioned there might still work.  What version of python and what distro are you using?

Comment: python 2.7 on fedora 21

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might need to update your version of `pip` itself.

Entertainingly, you can upgrade `pip` using `pip`, as per [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#upgrade-pip):

> On Debian and Ubuntu:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-pip
> ```
>
> On Fedora:
>
> ```
> sudo yum install python-pip
> ```