# How can I install ggplot on Python (Rodeo/Spyder)?

Tags: python, module, installation, anaconda, rodeo

I've been trying to install ggplot on [Rodeo](https://www.yhat.com/products/rodeo) for a while.
I read some topics such as [Installing ggplot for python failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967873/installing-ggplot-for-python-failed-with-error-code-1), [pip install numpy (python 2.7) fails with errorcode 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142839/pip-install-numpy-python-2-7-fails-with-errorcode-1) and [Error while installing ggplot in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539125/error-while-installing-ggplot-in-python). None of them addressed my issue (which might be something much simpler but I can't find the answer).

I also followed the guideline from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ggplot. It didn't work as well.

I keep getting the following error:

> pip install -U ggplot
>
> > SyntaxError: invalid syntax (< ipython-input-32-9868b8f5549e >, line 1)
> >
> > File " < ipython-input-32-9868b8f5549e > ", line 1
> >
> > pip install git+https://github.com/yhat/ggplot.git
> >
> > ```
> >          ^
> > ```
> >
> > SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What also happens is:

> import ggplot as ggplot
>
> > ImportError: No module named 'ggplot'
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> >
> > < ipython-input-22-66fae3902047 > in ()
> >
> > ----> 1 import ggplot as ggplot
> >
> > ImportError: No module named 'ggplot'

I've tried to use Spyder, but what I get there is the message "The following command must be run outside of the IPython shell:".

What am I missing? How can I use ggplot on Rodeo? Or at least on Spyder?

Answer (score 0):

In rodeo or spyder python, I worked the following code:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install','ggplot'])
from ggplot import *
```